# Controlling an Access SQL query from multiple combo boxes on a form

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got myself in a right mess following all kinds of semi-relevant tutorials trying to figure out how to send combo box fields residing on a form to a query.

I'm using the query to generate subsets of contact details from which to make labels for mailshot campaigns. I'd like the comboboxes to be either null or used in conjunction, so I can filter on combinations of choices.
I've got my comboboxes doing a lookup to retrieve their values and found a good tutorial on working with IS NULL, but I don't understand the VBA necessary create 'view results' and 'clear form' command buttons.

These are the names of my comboboxes as referenced in the query fields criteria:

```
[Forms]![SearchForm]![cboStatus]
[Forms]![SearchForm]![cboNewsletter]
```

These fields are called Status and Description respectively.

The query I'm filtering is called

```
qryFilter
```

These are the names of my Command buttons:

```
cmdResults 
cmdClear
```

cmdResults should send each of the combo box values to the query whether they are null or selected, but I cant get it working and clear should make the comboboxes null.

I'd be looking to expand this to include more criteria but I want to get it working first!

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance,
Rob

EDIT:
Tried to adapt this code from Patrick:

```
Private Sub cmdResults_Click()
 Dim tsSql As String
 tsSql = "SELECT * FROM qryAll WHERE "

If cboNewsletter <> "" And Not IsNull(cboNewsletter) Then
 tsSql = tsSql & "qryCorrespondence.NID = " & cboNewsletter & " "
    If (cboStatus <> "" And Not IsNull(cboStatus)) Then
    tsSql = tsSql & " AND "
    End If
 End If

If cboStatus <> "" And Not IsNull(cboStatus) Then
  tsSql = tsSql & "tblCustomers.Status = " & cboStatus & " "
End If

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open tsSql, CurrentProject.AccessConnection, 3, 3
End Sub
```

The last line gives me an error though, it highlights the following line in the debugger:

```
    rs.open tsSql, CurrentProject.AccessConnection, 3, 3,
```

And says syntax error in WHERE clause

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the error that your getting?  its trying to create a recordset... which might not even been what you ultimately need to do with it.  your query that you are writing, what does it apply to on the form?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'm hoping to use the query to just create subsets of my client database on the fly, i.e list current customers that we've not contacted for over a month, or potential customers that havent received anything. I was then hoping to insert the generated tables into a table for records where relevant. *edited my original post*

Comment: to determine what is wrong with the sql you can put a break point on the button click event, and then in the immediate window do a ?tssl after it adds the filter.  it will give you the string representation of what the sql is... its easier to look at that way.  that tsSql string can then be pretty much used for anything,  i generally use sup forms and set the source to the tssql, it looks pretty good that way.

Comment: and you can probably get rid of the rs.open line then.

Comment: Been using Debug.Print and all I get from the tsSql string is *SELECT * FROM qryAll WHERE*. Looks like it's not liking the IF statements?

Comment: are either of your drop down boxes null or empty strings?  if you put a break point on the dim of the tssql you can step through it and see exactly what is going on... if both of your drop down boxes are/can be null or empty strings then the where needs its own if statement to determine if a where is even needed.

Comment: What's with using ADO here? Aside from the question of whether you need to open a recordset in the first place (what are you going to do with it once it's opened?), DAO is the natural data interface for data stored in Jet/ACE data files, or accessed via ODBC.

Comment: I believe he may have been confused by my example.  I use ADO due to requirements for accessing external data in SQL Server.

Comment: In an Access app (unless it's an ADP), the preferred approach is ODBC linked tables, which means DAO is preferred to ADO, no matter what back end is involved. ADO is generally used in Access apps only for those things that ADO can do that DAO cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical situation for a Query By Form interface. My practice is to have a subroutine in the form's module that writes the WHERE clause, something like this:

```
  Private Function GetWhere() As String
    Dim strTemp As String

    If Not IsNull(Me!cboStatus) Then
       strTemp = strTemp & " AND tblCustomers.Status = " & Chr(34) & Me!cmbStatus & Chr(34)
    End If
    If Not IsNull(Me!cboNewsletter) Then
       strTemp = strTemp & " AND qryCorrespondence.NID = " & Chr(34) & Me!cboNewsletter & Chr(34)
    End If
    strTemp = Mid(strTemp, 6)
    If Len(strTemp) > 0 Then
       GetWhere = " WHERE " & strTemp
    End If
  End Function
```

(the code above assumes that `tblCustomers.Status` and `qryCorrespondence.NID` are available in the SELECT statement of `qryAll`)

In the OnClick() event of cmdResults, you would use it this way:

```
  Dim strSQL As String

  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryAll"
  strSQL = strSQL & GetWhere()

  [do with strSQL whatever you want]
```

The above code would return all records if neither combo box has a value selected.

For your cmbClear, you'd just have code that sets the two combo boxes to Null.

Comment: Thanks for you answer David, it's helped me loads, my VBA knowledge is pretty bad but i'm learning. How do I pass the entire SQL string into a query rather than passing the form fields into a prebuilt query's SQL? I tried "DestinationList.RecordSource = strSQL" but to no avail!

Comment: I use the SQL string constructed in the above code for one of two things, either to insert records into a temp table, or to load them into a form. If you have a form where you'd like to display the records, then just set the form's Recordsource property to the SQL string.

Answer (score 2):

There really is no clean way to do this in Access.

Say I have three combo boxes named:

cmbName
cmbCity
cmbState

And a button named:

btnDoWork

Now If I want to run a query based on the contents of the combo buttons based on the button click It could look something like this:

```
Private Sub btnDoWork_Click()
     Dim tsSql as String
     tsSql = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE "

  If cmbName <> "" and Not ISNull(cmbName) Then
     tsSql = tsSql & "user_name = " & cmbName & " "
    if (cmbCity <> "" and Not IsNull(cmbCity)) or (cmbState <> "" and Not IsNull(cmbState))
         tsSql = tsSql & " AND "
    end if
 End If

 if cmbCity <> "" and not isnull(cmbcity) then
      tsSql = tsSql & "city = " & cmbcity & " "
      if cmbState <> "" and Not IsNull(cmbState) then
           tsSql = tsSql & " AND "
      end if
 end if

if cmbState <> "" and not is null(cmbState) then
      tsSql = tsSql & "state = " & cmbState
end if

MyControl.RowSource = tsSql

End Sub
```

I'm sure you can alter it to include nulls if you like.  My version excludes nulls.

If you are trying to return the results in a multicolumn list box or some other control you would need to make sure that the controls Row Source Type is set to Table/Query, and you would set the controls source as such:

```
MyControl.RowSource = tsSql
```

Comment: If I wanted to change this to just cmbName and cmbCity do I just delete the final if statement? Do the 3s on the penultimate line need to be replaced with 2s?

Comment: yes, and then you would have to delete the if statement that adds the AND with in the city check.  The threes represent the cursor type and locktype, so whatever type you plan on using to lock.  There is more info on that here: http://www.w3schools.com/ADO/met_rs_open.asp

Comment: I disagree that there's "no clean way to do this in Access." You just have to write the SQL on the fly.

Comment: compared to many other applications of sql, "writing SQL on the fly" is not exactly clean considering the abilities of other "enterprise" applications.

Comment: I think it's interesting. @Patrick, that you seem to consider Access an "enterprise" application (since you use the comparitive "other"). I don't know what applications you might be talking about, since there are only two such apps comparable to Access that I know of (FileMaker Pro and OpenOffice Base), and so far as I know they don't make this easy, either. I think the original question uses confusing terminology and perhaps I'm just interpreting the question differently. On the other hand, your answer writes on-the-fly SQL just like my answer, so we seem to be interpreting it the same.

Comment: By enterprise Im just refering to other (larger) applications that handle on the fly quering better (Ie business objects)  I'm not saying per-se that access is an enterprise application, but even apex is capable of handling on the fly querying in a more graceful fashion.

Comment: Access handles on-the-fly querying in multiple different ways. The particular approach chosen by the original questioner here may not be the best one or the easiest one, and I think the question itself demonstrates some fundamental misunderstandings of the process (or maybe it's just incorrect terminology). Seems to me that whatever "apex" is is likely an application into which its developers have created user-friendly querying tools. Access is not an application in that sense, but a database application builder, and thus won't have an application-specific querying tools.

Comment: So, in short, I think you're comparison is off-base -- you're comparing an application to an application development platform and complaining that the application-specific querying tools don't come prebuilt. That seems notably silly to me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a code whats work
type in query designer by the criteria the following:

`[Forms]![myForm]![myControl] OR [Forms]![myForm]![myControl] Is Null`
And if your qhestion was how to making the comobox null you will need to use
`comboBox = Null`
And not `comboBox =""` because this give the string an empty string, and `Null` is cleaning it completely.