# MS Access: Filter query combo box error

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

My issue: I have a query which filters data depending on what is entered into checkboxes, textboxes and comboboxes located in a form. All of this works perfectly fine except for one single combo box. If I enter data into this combo box, called 'cmbBodyType', regardless of what data I enter, it will return 0 results every time.

My code so far is very lengthy so i will paste it all below, then i will paste a snippet of the i have used to filter for a combo box.

```
    SELECT [Car Table].Car_VIN, [Car Table].Car_Class, [Car Table].Car_BodyType,
[Car Table].Car_Colour, [Car Table].Car_Make, [Car Table].Car_Model, [Car
Table].Car_EngineType, [Car Table].Car_TransmissionType, [Car
Table].Car_GPSAvailability, [Car Table].Car_BootSpace, [Car
Table].Car_FuelConsumptRate, [Car Table].Car_SeatNumber, [Car
Table].Car_GreenStarRating, [Car Table].Car_ANCAPSafetyRating, [Car
Table].Car_DriveType
FROM [Car Table]

       WHERE ((([Car Table].Car_VIN) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]!
    [NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtVIN] & "*") AND (([Car Table].Car_Class) Like "*"
    & [Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbClass] & "*") AND
    (([Car Table].Car_DriveType) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]!
    [NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbDriveType] & "*") AND (([Car Table].Car_BodyType)
    Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbBodyType] &
    "*") AND (([Car Table].Car_Colour) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]
    ![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbBodyType] & "*") AND (([Car Table].Car_Make)
    Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtMake] & "*")
    AND (([Car Table].Car_Model) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]
    ![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtModel] & "*") AND (([Car Table].Car_EngineType)
    Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbEngineType]
    & "*") AND (([Car Table].Car_TransmissionType) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation
    Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbTransmissionType] & "*") AND (([Car
    Table].Car_GPSAvailability) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]
    ![NavigationSubform].[Form]![ChGPSAvailability] & "*") AND (([Car
     Table].Car_SeatNumber) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]
    ![NavigationSubform].[Form]![txtSeatNumber] & "*") AND (([Car
     Table].Car_GreenStarRating) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]
    ![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbGreenStarRating] & "*") AND (([Car
     Table].Car_ANCAPSafetyRating) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]
    ![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbANCAPSafetyRating] & "*") AND
     ((Abs([car_fuelconsumptrate]-Nz([Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform]
    .[Form]![txtFuelConsumption],[car_fuelconsumptrate]))<=Nz([2],9999)))
AND ((Abs([car_bootspace]-Nz([Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]
![txtBootSpace], [car_BootSpace]))<=Nz([100],9999))));
```

snippet (this would be in the WHERE are, or to put it more simply, this is the critera displayed in design view):

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbBodyType] & "*"
```

Edit: it also seems that my 'green star rating' combobox makes no difference in the search regardless of its value. It seems that everything between the working and non-working comboboxes are the same... one thing i have noticed is that the two comboboxes that don't work both have a larger number of choices than the other, working, comboboxes.

Comment: What is the **Rowsource** for `cmbBodyType`? --- Also, if the comboboxes are only used to select a search parameter, you don't need to filter with `LIKE *...*`, you can do `= ...`. Only if users can also enter free text into the combobox you need LIKE.

Comment: BlueRhapsody: After seeing that you have built this search form over the last view days  I would highly recommend you to read this old post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432070/controlling-an-access-sql-query-from-multiple-combo-boxes-on-a-form?rq=1 And the checked answer from @David-W-Fenton. It is about how to create a query using VBA. The interesting part here is, that your query is shorter in the WHERE statements because there are only the LIKE statements, that you really need!

Comment: @asdev thanks for the recommendation, but the amount of VBA i am allowed to use is harshly restricted. I'll go over it for future knowledge though!

Comment: @Andre451 my row source is the following: "Hatchback";"Coupe";"Convertible";"Minivan";"SUV";"Ute";"Sedan";"Luxury";"Other".     I will try getting rid of the like, but i added that in according to a different tutorial (for text boxes) which used it to allow the field to be blank. EDIT: removed the 'like' and as you said it works fine, but the overarching problem remains.

Comment: @BlueRhapsody: alright. I thought perhaps the comboboxes might be wizard-generated with 2 columns. I have no idea why the value list wouldn't work. --- Good point about the NULL (blank) parameter fields. I always construct query-by-form SQL dynamically, so that didn't cross my mind. You (or your employer) really should consider using that VBA solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a part in your WHERE statement like that

```
   ...AND [Car Table].Car_BodyType Like 
               IIf(IsNull([Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbBodyType]),"*" ,
               [Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbBodyType])...
```

Found at [MS Access Search Form need to pass values from unbound combo box to query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120980/ms-access-search-form-need-to-pass-values-from-unbound-combo-box-to-query?rq=1)
Read it for further explanation, also the comments.

BTW:

```
(([Car Table].Car_Colour) Like "*" & [Forms]![Navigation Form]
    ![NavigationSubform].[Form]![cmbBodyType] & "*")
```

You search in Car_color from cmbBodyType

Be careful with this huge SQL

EDIT: Star rating system: What type is this field? If it is a number field, LIKE does not apply. LIKE is meant for text afaik.

Comment: Thanks haha, I actually realised that and posted my own solution literally a minute after you made that edit (deleted it now). Sorry for wasting your time. Also, by star rating system, do you mean the greenstarrating? that's a combo box that holds numerical (1...5) and text (N/A) values. Also, i should mention that i tried getting rid of the seemingly unnecessary 'like' code; and it initially seemed to work, but if i left a field null it would return no results.

Comment: Okay, so having N/A it is a textBased Combobox. What is the field typ in the table?

Comment: The combobox is a short text data type (i'm assuming field type and data type are the same, but you never know with programming haha)

Comment: You are right, correctly it is datatype. I meant the datatype of column in the table: ([Car Table].Car_GreenStarRating)

Comment: And the field is a short text type.. right? I'm not sure if that's what you mean

Comment: With short text type in the table, the LIKE operator should apply, so you should be able to use the IIF statement here also.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll keep that in mind, but for now you've already solved my problem ^.^ thanks