# use multiple criterias on select clause in sql access

Tags: ms-access

I have to select criterias from access form and use then in `SELECT` clause in `sql` Access. i want to use the result on the query for a report. the picture of the form showing the criterias that i want to select from and this is the my `query`:

```
SELECT MatchesT.Position, MatchesT.Date, MatchesT.Amount,       
       MatchesT.Reference, MatchesT.Branch, 
       MatchesT.MatchDate, MatchesT.Employee
FROM MatchesT
WHERE MatchesT.Position=Forms!Matches_Check!cbposition 
   AND MatchesT.Date Between Forms!Matches_Check!txtdate1 
   AND Forms!Matches_Check!txtdate2 
   AND  MatchesT.Amount=Forms!Matches_Check!txtamount 
   AND MatchesT.Reference=Forms!Matches_Check!txtreference 
   AND MatchesT.Branch=Forms!Matches_Check!txtbranch 
   AND MatchesT.MatchDate Between Forms!Matches_Check!txtmatchdate1 
   AND Forms!Matches_Check!txtmatchdate2  
   AND MatchesT.Employee=Forms!Matches_Check!txtteammember;
```

[image]

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: when i click RUN does not display the selection that i am looking for from the table

Comment: It will probably **only** work if you put parameters in every field, but not with empty search fields. There is a similar question right next door: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717361/ms-access-filter-query-combo-box-error -- read the comments and links.